# How to use the Reddit API to only scrape videos?

Tags: python, praw

I am trying to use [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to fetch posts from a particular subreddit.

This is my code:

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=PERSONAL_USE_SCRIPT,
                     client_secret=SECRET,
                     user_agent="useragent")

for submission in reddit.subreddit("funnyvideos").hot(limit=10):
   print(submission.title)
```

The output consists of all top 10 hot topics with their title. This includes posts which has both videos and non-videos posts.

How can I apply a filter so that it ***only fetches the posts which has a video in it*** and exclude all others?

Comment: You could check the `Submission.url` attribute for certain extensions like mp4.  Reference: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/models/submission.html

Comment: url dont have any extension

Answer (score 1):

To filter out posts to only those containing videos you could do this:

```
for submission in reddit.subreddit("funnyvideos").hot(limit=10):
    if submission.is_video:
        # submission.url will give the url to the video
        print(submission.title)
```